# best practice: mysql remote mobile devices sync over 3G connection

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, 3g

currently we have one master mysql server that connect every 1 hour to 100 remote mobile devices [vehicles] over 3G connection [not very reliable: get disconnect daily while sync in progress for few cars]. the sync done through .net windows service tool. after checking the remote mysql status the master start perform the sync. sometimes the sync payload data is about **6-8 MB**. the sync performed for one table only using non-transactional approach.

mysql server version in use is: 4.1.22

**Questions**:

1. is it useful to make the sync transactional knowing that only one table getting sync? or no value added!
2. the sync data loaded to remote machine using mysql statement:

   LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

   the file format is CSV. how i can send the data in compressed format? without developing   tool that reside on the remote device.
3. is it good practice or architecture in the sync domain to deploy remote application that will perform the sync after sending the data or it should be done directly by the master? i mean the development of tool that will reside on remote machine will be difficult to update or fix in case new requirements appear. but it will save a lot of bandwidth for the sync operation and it will eliminate the errors that could raise from the live master sync in case disconnection occur while the sync is in-progress. so if this is recommend then only compressed data will be sent, then by using some sort of check-sum I'll verify that the whole data sent otherwise the request will be initiated again.

please share your thoughts and experience.

thanks,

Comment: What kind of devices are being used?

Comment: device is laptop with industrial specs and MS-Win-XP-Pro as OS.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is each client talking directly to the mysql server or is each client using a type of RESTful connection to a backend server that talks to mysql (could be whatever, php page, custom python, c++ server). What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you worried mainly about the errors happening (data not going through properly?). Going through a backend RESTful server will eliminate most of your problems as you'll be able to check that the data is correct before it gets entered into your database...

Comment: also, it looks like the Server is initiating the sync and not the clients, i would change that to client initiated w/ just the server handling the data... a much more forward and expandable method.

Comment: @g19fanatic currently the master mysql connect to each client mysql through windows service app [.net, dev in-house]. i told this in the first paragraph. so no RESTful back-end being used. regarding the 2nd point, yes server init the sync. so you say if client init is more forward!! can you proof this under architecture standards of server-client sync ops.

Comment: this is simply the way things are done... Look at almost every single type of server out there that must 'sync' data... Websites that serve RSS feeds do not automatically send it out to people, client software goes out and pings it to sync for the clients software. Dropbox is a perfect example of a client inited syncing service. The server initing is old hat thinking and not the way things are done.

Comment: @g19fanatic that's great help! thanks for sharing your thoughts and exp. i think you should post your inputs as full answer to the 3 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would change the approach to a client inited sync vs a server inited sync. A many to one vs one to many approach will expand much easier than your current setup. My above comments give a few good examples of a required client to server syncing.

Secondly, Turn on transactional record entry. There is no reason not to have it. This will guarentee that the information gets entered in a timely fashion and will be able to possibly provide even more 'meta-data' (such as which clients are slow to update, etc...).

Lastly, you can 'enhance' this uploading by taking a different look at it. If you were to implement a sort of service at the server side that takes in a response via a POST from the client, you'd be able to send the data to the server side with no issues. It would be just like 'uploading' a file to a server. Once your 6-8 MB file is 'uploaded' it is then put into the database. The great thing about this is if your server is an APACHE (or even in your case an IIS server), you'd be able to have every single client uploading data at the same time without much of an issue. At that point, uploading to the mysql server via an insert would take virtually no time and your process would continue on without a problem.

This is the way I'd handle your situation...